# App Not showing in Google Search results even after App-Indexing

Tags: android, android-app-indexing

I have followed and completed all the steps required for app-indexing  our  website

http://tcsworld10k.procamrunning.in/ .

**Our website is mapped to the app**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bangalore.marathon2014 here.

Google Search still shows the same results No change, No app is showing in search results. There is no way to debug why it is happening. We have completed all the steps including Verify Website but nothing is working. App is not showing in Google search results as documented and working for others.

I have followed all the steps mentioned here

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/app

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6041489

I got a mail from Webmaster tool too for successful verification of website.

If you indexed your app, please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Did you fix it? How? I'm currently in the same situation as you hehe

Answer (score 2):

There are some new tools just announced last week that may help.  See here:  http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/05/rolling-out-red-carpet-for-app-owners.html

Check the Crawl Errors and Fetch as Google sections and see if you find any useful information about what's going on with your app.

Comment: Actually I don't have webmaster tools access, is there any way to get all notification on Google play email id too. After all both are linked so it will be good to report application specific bugs to Play Console's email id. BTW after connecting to website team I got to know about a bug and fixed it now it is visible on some devices ,that is also not consistent. Sometimes app shows below the url in search results, after refreshing, it disappears. On some devices not at all showing. On some it shows under "More content in APP" section. Why this inconsistency, Not understanding ?